# How to keep submit button visible and executable upon textarea onblur

Tags: jquery, blur

I have a `<div id="comment_posting_holder">` tag that holds a form with two elements: a textarea box and a submit button.

I want to have the div tag (containing the textarea and submit button) disappear if I click somewhere "OTHER" than the submit button.  I have a start for the code below.  So upon leaving focus from the textarea, I can make the div tag disappear.

The problem is that if the div disappears, so does the submit button which means I cannot submit the form!  How can I fix this?

Any suggestions?  Thank you!

**Facebook does this with it's comments.  If you click on a "Post your comment..." field the textarea appears and then it will disappear upon losing focus other than if you pressed the submit button.

```
$('textarea').blur(function() {
     $('#comment_posting_holder').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want an implementation like facebook, you need to check if someone has written something in the textbox.

**You can see my answer working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fqfsh/)**

HTML

```
<div>
   <textarea class="comment_empty">Write a comment</textarea><br />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var submit = $("#submit");

    $("textarea").blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val("Write a comment")
                   .removeClass("comment_filled")
                   .addClass("comment_empty");
            submit.hide();
        }
    }).focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "Write a comment") {
            $(this).val("")
                   .removeClass("comment_empty")
                   .addClass("comment_filled");
            submit.show();
        }
    });
});
```

some CSS

```
.comment_empty {
   color: gray;
   height: 30px;
}

.comment_filled {
   color: black;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**What I understand you want:**

If the user clicks anywhere, and the element that was clicked was not the submit button, then hide the div.

**Code to do that:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == "idOfSubmitButton") {
      //user clicked the submit button (make sure to give it an ID)
      //if you wanted to be really hardcore, you could submit the form here via AJAX
    }
    else {
      //user clicked anywhere on the page but the submit button
      //here you'd want to check and make sure someone has actually typed
      //something in the textarea, otherwise this will happen for every
      //click on a hyperlink, button, image, et cetera on the page
      $('#comment_posting_holder').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Was is not working because of the syntax error in your code. Other than the missing single quote, what you have looks good, so long as it is in an event that is actually firing. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').blur(function() {
        $('#comment_posting_holder').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay I typed it wrong above but no that's not the issue.  See here's the problem... the submit button disappears ALSO.  I do not want it to disappear!  I can't submit the form then.  See my point?  Since the div tag itself holds the textarea and the submit button, once the textarea loses focus, everything disappears!

I just want everything to disappear only if I click anywhere else which is what this part of the code will do yes.  But, the moment I put my mouse and click on the submit button everything goes away.